# keypress function does not work on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web form project in which i want to insert my data into a textbox using keypress..

this is my aspx file

```
 <asp:Textbox runat ="server" id="Scan" style="width:1200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000; background-color:white"></asp:Textbox>
```

the aspx.cs file

```
private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            string strSql;
            string en ;
            en = desk;



            //if (e.KeyChar == Strings.Chr(13))
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {

                string strDeskNo = (Scan.Text);//sepatutnya ada Trim(Scan.Text)
                strSql = "Insert into  ";// sql statement

                if (strDeskNo == "")
                {
                    Scan.Style.Add("color", "red");
                    Scan.Text = "Please scan again ! ";



                    msgBoxOpen = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no desk no entered! Please Scan again.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    msgBoxOpen = false;



                    Scan.Text = "";
                    Scan.Style.Add("background-color", "white");
                    Scan.Focus();


                    return;
                }

                e.Handled = true;
}
}
```

when i run the program..the textbox does not working even for the error messages.. 
I have tried

1. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/376421/Csharp-Keydown-or-keycode-not-working
2. ["KeyPress" event for WinForms textbox is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571297/keypress-event-for-winforms-textbox-is-missing)

does anyone knows how to fix this? Thank you so much

Comment: Winforms != Webforms. You have not assigned a handler to the textbox in your aspx. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox?view=netframework-4.8 . The closest you have in webforms is `OnTextChanged`.  For most "key press" actions in webforms you would want to work with javascript so you are not doing a full request - response process with a page reload for every key press.

Comment: @JonP thanks sir ! i realize my mistake